# Changing click-drag delay setting?

Tags: mouse, settings, input

To drag something with the mouse, it seems I have to hold the mouse button down for a fraction of a second before dragging (dragging immediately after clicking does not work).

I don't like this, but can't find any setting in the 'mouse & touchpad' settings to change it.  Is there any way to reduce this delay?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, though it seems to come and go, depending on system updates from Canonical.

Interestingly, it was happening earlier to me until I plugged in an external USB mouse to test with.  Now things are working perfectly, even when I remove the external USB mouse.  By the way, my system is a Dell Vostro 2420 laptop with a trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

And now it's back again, at least with the trackpad.  External USB mouse works fine when I plug it in.  It seemed to go bad after I did a two-finger click-drag to scroll with the trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that's worked for me is toggling the input device on and off.

First you find the input device that's misbehaving:

```
foo@machine:$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Then you toggle that ID on and off, for me it's always been the Synaptics TouchPad (ID=11):

```
foo@machine:$ xinput set-prop 11 "Device Enabled" 0
foo@machine:$ xinput set-prop 11 "Device Enabled" 1
```

And now its all working again, I think this is definitely a bug. I've randomly observed it across 3 different laptops, but haven't had the change to debug it.

Comment: This worked for me - thanks! (On openSUSE, in fact.)  Yes, agree it definitely looks like a bug.