# On ubuntu 18.04 how do increase the mouse Drag Delay Time?

Tags: 18.04, mount

When I play on chess.com, the chess pieces can be dragged or clicked. When I click for too long, it is treated as a drag. However if I click fast enough, it treats it like a click. Not sure how to change this behavior, but was thinking there was some sort of drag delay time that is being triggered through ubuntu, as this functionality has sometimes caused error for other people see [Changing click-drag delay setting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697906/changing-click-drag-delay-setting)

Comment: While I don't know how to resolve this issue, I can suggest something for chess.com. Click on the piece you intend to move, and click on its destination. Do not drag. Dragging often leads to accidental placements of pieces.

Comment: I do that already. However It bugs me that if I don't click fast enough, the piece gitters (as if I'm dragging it)